# Issue With SSRS Emailing Reports As PDFs

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008

I have a strange issue that I'm unable to find the answer to online or by looking at it myself.

Basically when I set up an email subscription for a report I've created in SSRS Report Builder (2008); I can render my report into any format other than PDF and it will be sent to me successfully. The report is a table that returns some client information from our recruiting database; nothing complicated and it does work correctly if I choose another format.

If I try and send as a PDF I receive the error:
'Failure sending mail: The transport lost its connection to the server.'

I can export the report into PDF format if I run it from the report designer and the file size for the fully rendered PDF is ~35kb so I can't imagine a timeout.

It is baffling me and I'd like to know the root cause.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since it's so small, I can't imagine a timeout there either. It doesn't sound like the generation is the issue. Have you checked nslookup and DNS on the domain you are trying to send to (even it's the same domain, a bad DNS server might cause a timeout) Also, do you have any issues sending email via t-sql? Have your network guys checked your smtp server for issues?

Comment: Just for test, can you generate PDF file when you select "Windows File Share" as delivery option, instead of Email ? Also, this is the whole error you see if you are looking at SSRS log file ?

Comment: Yes, I can generate PDFs using the file share method.

As for my logfile; I keep seeing a reference to the following:

`emailextension!WindowsService_63!2660!03/05/2013-15:17:22:: e ERROR: Error sending email. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040212): The transport lost its connection to the server`.

Comment: Network guy is in tomorrow so I will see if he can shed any more light - Thanks

Comment: Good luck! Let us know the results, maybe they can give us a clue to go further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another part of this puzzle was that the files that weren't able to send were created in a temporary location where they would then be deleted.

This issue is now completely resolved - in brief (after several false starts such as checking file/folder permissions and discovering reports would be sent via subscription as pdf if they contained a graph and not a matrix); we ended up using SMTP (set up on SQL Server) to send the email from the SQL Server to Exchange, which would then handle the rest of the journey.

Thank you all for your suggestions.